# Cannot install iTunes- iPod Service error

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, itunes, services

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I have had problems with the service starting before, fixed by manually starting it, and I have had problems installing updates. So, I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it again. When reinstalling it, it has problems installing and starting the iPod Service.